# Cannot assign more than 3584 mb of ram for guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ram

I am using Ubuntu 64 bit host operating system and have installed VirtualBox Version 5.1.8 r111374 (Qt5.5.1). I cannot create more than 3584 MB Ram for guest Operating System irrespective of which operating system and their versions. I have 16 GB ram in host operating system. How can I assign more than 3584 MB of ram to guest OS

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250573/virtualbox-kernel-modules-do-not-match-the-version-of-virtualbox) solved my problem. I had installed VirtualBox with .deb file directly, instead what I had to do was to install from "Debian-based Linux distributions" section by scrolling down the [VirtualBox downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), and follow the instructions.