# Virtual box kernel does not match the modules

Tags: virtualbox

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful.
Executing'/sbin/vboxconfig' may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 ERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user
```

`dpkg --list | grep virtualbox`

```
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox  0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1 all VirtualBox scope for Unity
ii  virtualbox-5.1:i386 5.1.12-112440~Ubuntu~xenial i386 Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

Already tried solutions from link [VirtualBox kernel modules do not match the version of VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250573/virtualbox-kernel-modules-do-not-match-the-version-of-virtualbox)

my secure boot is also disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i rebooted the pc unistalled virtual box.
    sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.1:i386
then reinstalled a previous version and it worked succesfully

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the that:

1. The official Virtualbox in the Ubuntu repo is usually older than the one you install from the *official Virtualbox download page*.
2. If you have to install [a newer version] from a different source, then you have to :

   - uninstall the one that comes from Ubuntu repo and this should be done with the command `sudo apt remove --purge` so that the *virtualbox kernel modules* will also be removed.
3. Then download the latest for your *Ubuntu version* and simply install and it will be build new *virtualbox kernel modules* that will *match* your virtualbox version.
4. If you don't need the latest version then simply install with:

   ```
   sudo apt install virtualbox
   ```

The steps stated here [in your included link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250573/virtualbox-kernel-modules-do-not-match-the-version-of-virtualbox) will still work.